# iOS how to serialize CVPixelBufferRef to be sent in a NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, avfoundation, core-video

I have a client-server application, where the client sends processed images to the server. I would like the client to send these as CVPixelBufferRef, so the server can combine images easier. The client sends data as NSDictionary.

**How do I send a core foundation/core video object over network within a NSDictionary?**

```
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          size.width,
                                          size.height,
                                          kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                          (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);
//If I try this:
    NSDictionary* dataToSend = @{@"data":pxbuffer};
//Get Compiler Error: Collection element of type 'CVPixelBufferRef' (aka '__CVBuffer *') is not an Objective-C object
```

Comment: Did you find the way how to do it?